# Deno validasaur module has no exported member

Tags: typescript, docker, deno

I have imported [Validasaur](https://github.com/emsifa/validasaur) via a dependancy file (deps.ts):

```
export {
  validate,required,nullable,isBool,isDate,
  isString,lengthBetween,flattenMessages,
  firstMessages,ValidationRules,Validity,
  invalid,Rule,notNull
} from 'https://deno.land/x/validasaur/mod.ts';
```

I'm importing these into my and try importing it into a model file via:

```
import {
  lengthBetween,
  required,
  isBool,
  isString,
  isDate,
  nullable,
  notNull,
} from '../../deps.ts';

interface ITodo {
  name: string;
  title: string;
  description?: string;
  done: boolean;
  colour?: string;
  endAt: Date;
  createdOn: Date;
  updatedOn?: Date;
}

const todoSchema: ITodo = {
  name: [notNull, lengthBetween(5, 100), isString, required],
  title: [notNull, lengthBetween(5, 100), isString, required],
  description: [isString, nullable],
  done: [isBool, required],
  colour: [isString, nullable],
  endAt: [isDate, nullable],
  createdOn: [isDate, required],
  updatedOn: [isDate, nullable],
};

export { todoSchema, ITodo };
```

and get the error:

```
error: TS2305 [ERROR]: Module '"file:///usr/app/deps.ts"' has no exported member 'lengthBetween'.
lengthBetween,
~~~~~~~~~~~~~
at file:///usr/app/src/model/todoModel.ts:2:3
```

What am I missing here? I've read over the module's docs and think I'm importing correctly, I've triple-checked spelling and and names. I really don't see what the hangup is... Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure you're improting the correct deps.ts? Your title suggests "validasaur module has no exported member `lengthBetween`" but the error points to deps.ts. I wrote a short test programm and it works fine with an import via `deps.ts`

Comment: I only have one reps.ts file. If it was the wrong path I’d get a reference error, right?

Comment: sure, that would cause a "error: Cannot resolve module ...". I can't see any obvious problem in your code. I tried both ways, importing directly from "https://deno.land/x/validasaur/mod.ts" and indirectly via deps.ts, both worked fine, the latter after I deleted  "ValidationRules,Validity" from deps, becaused that caused another error. Did you try importing directly?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

Turns out that the issue had nothing to do with Deno or TypeScript. I had a cached version of the deps.ts file on a docker image that wasn't rebuilt properly. Once I did that it was fine (though now I'm resolving --isolatedModules errors).